# If $u \in H^2_0$ and $v \in H^1_0$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

If $u \in H^2_0$ and $v \in H^1_0$, I would like to show that
$$\forall v \in H^1_0, \mbox{if}~a(u,v) = 0, \forall u \in H^2_0~\mbox{then}~v = 0,$$
where $a(u,v) = \langle Lu,v \rangle$ and $Lu = a(x) u^{(4)} + b(x) u''' + c(x) u'' + d(x) u' +e(x) u$. Also $a(x), b(x), c(x), d(x)$ and $e(x)$ are bounded nonzero functions on the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: this result is wrong if $a=b=c=d=e=0$.

Comment: I can put the conditions on these functions. So I will update the post to have nonzero functions. Thanks

Comment: Your notation is unclear. You have a bilinear form $a(.,.)$ and you want to show $\forall u, a(u,v) = 0 \implies v =0$. If $v \ne 0$, you need to construct $u$ such that $a(u,v) \ne 0$

Comment: I can restate what I want as follows $$\sup_{u \in H^2_0} a(u,v) > 0~~\forall v \in H^1_0, v\neq 0$$